# Identify when a question's dupe is about to be deleted

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions, vote-to-delete

[**Edit:** this issue was fixed last year from system improvements - Have voted to close as *no longer repro*]

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39555/for-meta-allow-1-rep-users-to-comment) is marked as "Possible Dupe" but the possible dupe is no longer accessible.

I presumed there would be a script which checks a question that is about to be deleted to first determine if it's linked to as a dupe.

If not, is there any reason?

From there you could either not allow deletion (possibly depending on rep level), or allow it.

In either case, raise a flag so the issue can be fixed. Maybe under *review*:

> Due to the removal of the original dupe, should this question be:
>
> - Duped with another question;
> - Is now unique and dupe notice to be removed;

Without such a feature, a break in the chain of info/data resources is introduced whenever a question is deleted which had other question(s) linking to it as a dupe.

Comment: You're missing a third option there: "- Should be deleted too" - Because let's face it, oftentimes a dupe being deleted means that question linking to it should *also* be deleted.

Comment: hmm, we get onto a lot of parameters now though. "#3 Should be deleted too" - What if dupe and original are valid, and original violates (copyright, whatever), or user deletes account, or requests all questions to be removed/just that question? What if the answers on dupe and/or original are decent, worthy of retaining the question. Perhaps only just retaining it for search terms (removing any content, unless tripe, is not really a good thing as any (99.9%)  external links into Stack are good). I don't disagree with you, but you open a can of worms with #3

Comment: It's very, *very* rare that I ever come across a question closed as a duplicate of a deleted post that shouldn't also be deleted. In fact, that question you linked is probably the first one I've ever reopened matching that scenario.

Comment: @animuson Here though, I'm talking solely about avoiding having links to duplicate questions being broken due to the original being removed. If you deem a dupe needs deleting, then surely this falls under whatever "clean up" policies and systems Stack has in place? Besides, if a dupe's *linked question* is deleted, and the dupe is assessed then and deemed to require deleting, then surely the dupe shouldn't have been marked as dupe in the first place? This would suggest community/review/flags are failing.

Comment: Note: one can't delete a question that is the target of another closed as duplicate question anymore.

Comment: @MichaelT Yeah I edited the question a while ago to reflect that. Have voted to close as *no longer repro*.